# Why _(underscore) ignored in output?

Tags: go

I would like to know the reason behind the output of this program.

```
package main
```

**Program**

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 1_00_000
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

**Output**

`100000`

How come the underscore is ignored in the output. What is the use of this new feature in Go?

Comment: It is useful to make large constants more readable in the source code.

Comment: For the same reason why `a := 0x186a0 ; fmt.Println(a)` prints `100000` and not `0x186a0`.

Comment: Are you asking why the decision was made to support that syntax, or what that syntax means? The former is opinion based, and off-topic. The latter is just a matter of reading the spec.

Comment: Why all the down-votes??! I've been using `go` a long time and didn't know you could add these type of decorators. So I learned something new from this question.

Comment: @colminator: Probably because it's off-topic, and shows no research effort. As for you not knowing about this--that's not surprising, as it's only been possible for less than two weeks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not ignored in the output; it's ignored in the source code. The underscores are a convenience to make large number literals in code easier to read; the literal is still an integer, and integers don't contain underscores. You could always use a string of course:

```
a := "1_00_000"
fmt.Println(a)
```

Underscores as separators were added as a new feature in Go 1.13: https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#language

Answer (score 4):

Underscores are just digit separators.This new feature is introduced in Go 1.13 to improve readability.It is not printed along with the number.

The digits of any number literal can be separated (grouped) using underscores, such as in 1_000_000, 0b_1010_011 to make it more readable.

```
d := 9795696874578
d := 9_795_696_874_578 // thousand separators
```

Here underscored literals are much easier to read.